# What can be turned into a docker image?

Tags: tomcat, docker, jsp

Assume I have the the following VM:

```
-Centos
-JRE 1.8
-Tomcat
-Jar dependencies
-My WAR file + all the server configuration files
```

Now can I turn this whole thing into one Docker image, excluding the Centos? So next time I deploy it as a container it's all ready and started without doing any additional work. I simply load the web app on a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! A better way would be use [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) *OR*:

[Apache Tomcat is an open source implementation of the Java Servlet and JavaServer Pages technologies](https://hub.docker.com/_/tomcat/)